# Longstaff Schwartz with future conditional coupons

Tags: option-pricing, monte-carlo, derivatives, american-options, longstaff-schwartz

I've implemented the L-S algorithm for a simple put option. I want to value a more complex derivative which has future conditional coupons which only occur if the option is in the money. How would I incorporate that feature into my model?

Comment: How have you implemented it for a put option? if you orthogonalize the payoff and path generation code then it should become more obvious.

Comment: @will I’ve done that exactly. So I need the discounted cash flow at the next time step if the put is not exercised at the given time step. How would I incorporate future potential coupons?